# get customer details from observer event 'checkout_submit_all_after'

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to get the **customer object** from the  `checkout_submit_all_after`

This is the observer event for when the customer registers as new customer while also making a purchase. i.e on the one page checkout

i am able to catch the event in my method.

my only issue now is how to get the customer object .

i tried this but  it came up with null.

```
$observer->getEvent()->getCustomer()
```

Comment: this event will not provide customer object, only order and quote object is provided.

Comment: it does if the user also regsiters. i checked it and saw that its there. but not sure how to pull it out

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: Happy to help !! Happy coding :) You can give upvote also :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get customer details like this :

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$customer_id = $order->getCustomerId();
$customerData = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($customerData->getData());
```

Hope, It maybe helpful for you.